# related field making reference to many2one field wrong behavior

Tags: python, field, odoo

I have this class:

```
class caracteristica_fisica(osv.osv):
    _name = 'caracteristica.fisica'
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Nombre',required=True),
 }
```

In product category, I have a many2one field making reference to *caracteristica.fisica* model:

```
class caracteristica_fisica(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'product.category'
    _name = 'product.category'
    _columns = {
     'cf1':fields.many2one('caracteristica.fisica', 'Característica física 1')
    }
```

Once I select this many2one *cf1* field, I need this value to generate a record in *comun.denominador* table:

```
class comun_denominador(osv.osv):
    _name='comun.denominador'
    _columns = {
          'categ_id' : fields.many2one('product.category','Categoría de Producto', select=True, ondelete='cascade'),
          'cf1_cm': fields.related('categ_id', 'cf1', string="Característica física 1", type='char', store=True, select=True),
     }
```

It generates the record in *comun.denominador,* but in this format:

```
caracteristica.fisica(4,)
```

and I need it to show the real name

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
class comun_denominador(osv.osv):
    _name='comun.denominador'
    _columns = {
          'categ_id' : fields.many2one('product.category','Categoría de Producto', select=True, ondelete='cascade'),
          'cf1_cm': fields.related('categ_id', 'cf1', string="Característica física 1", type='many2one', relation="caracteristica.fisica", store=True, select=True),
     }
```

The related field that you are trying to access is not of type "char", but a "many2one" field.

**Note:**

One more thing, if your purpose for having a related field just for the information purpose, don't make it "store=True" and make it readonly.

Comment: I need it for search purposes in 'comun.denominador' model, so I need to store it, I have tried your suggestion, but it still displays the record in the same way, I desinstalled my custom module and installed again, could there be other reason? Thanks!

Comment: hi again, this is system log:

Comment: openerp.fields: Field comun.denominador.cf1_cm with unknown comodel_name 'caracteristica.fisica'    This is strange I already installed this model.

Comment: please uninstall your module and check. or change the field name of the related field and check